# Simple algorithms that can be implemented on a FPGA

Tags: algorithm, fpga

I am new to FPGA programming and was planning on implementing several algorithms that may become useful in future to me when I am doing my projects. So, I wanted to ask for suggestions on things I could implement on FPGA (specially some interesting algorithms) ordered in difficulty level. Thank you!

Comment: Hmmm, random number generator, CRC generator, Reed-Solomon encoder, MPEG4 video encoder. Let me know if you get that last one done, I'll be impressed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the suggestions in the comment are really awesome. But you said you are beginner that's why I would suggest 
that

> implement a 64 bit ALU with addition,subtraction, multiplication or
>   division. The last two seems easy but they have pretty decent
>   algorithm in terms of computers.

---

For easy implementation you can first go for 4/8 bit ALU..then extend it to 64 bit one. It takes some time to grasp the whole idea. Give it a try of you want.

After that you can obviously go for CRC-generator, then Reed Solomon encoder , Random number generator and MPEG4 video encoder like **user3386109** said.

Comment: Thank you! That is what i was looking for, start with easy stuff and progress towards more difficult ones.

Comment: @Blizzard.: Basially you can follow some courses..they deal with these matters step by step. All the best